# SpriteKit label rendering order

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm learning SpriteKit and as an example I tried to add few `SKSpriteNode`s on the scene each with a label. Here is how my node graph should look (code sample is below):

`Scene
|
+-- SpriteNode1
|   |
|   +-- SpriteNode2
|   +-- LabelNode1
|
+-- SpriteNode2
    |
    +-- SpriteNode3
    +-- LabelNode2`

According to the [documentation from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Nodes/Nodes.html) SpriteKit should render SpriteNode1, then its children, then SpriteNode2 then its children. However the rendering result that I got clearly shows that `SKLabelNode`s are rendered after the other elements, so the label in the `SpriteNode1` overlap label in `SpriteNode2`.

What I tried to achieve is to draw a simple playing card with text on it.

Here is what rendering result looks like:

[image: rendering result]

Here is a code snippet:

```
-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {

    [self addDummyNodeAt: CGPointMake(500, 500)];
    [self addDummyNodeAt: CGPointMake(550, 520)];
}

-(void)addDummyNodeAt: (CGPoint) point {
    // Create a sprite
    SKSpriteNode* sprite = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithColor:[self getRandomColor] size:CGSizeMake(165, 220)];
    sprite.position = point;
    [self addChild:sprite];

    // Add another color rectangle as a node to a sprite
    SKSpriteNode * testNode = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithColor:[self getRandomColor] size:CGSizeMake(120, 50)];
    testNode.position = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    [sprite addChild: testNode];

    // Add a text
    SKLabelNode *cardLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Tahoma"];
    cardLabel.text = @"This is a text";
    cardLabel.fontColor = [SKColor blackColor];
    cardLabel.fontSize = 12;
    cardLabel.position = CGPointMake(-22, -70);
    [sprite addChild: cardLabel];
}

-(UIColor*) getRandomColor {
    CGFloat hue = ( arc4random() % 256 / 256.0 );
    CGFloat saturation = ( arc4random() % 128 / 256.0 ) + 0.5;
    CGFloat brightness = ( arc4random() % 128 / 256.0 ) + 0.5;
    return [UIColor colorWithHue:hue saturation:saturation brightness:brightness alpha:1];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your view controller check that

```
skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = false
```

and you can set the

```
sprite.zPosition=1
```

to manually control the order the sprites are drawn in.

Comment: Thank you very much, the first line of code (`ignoresSiblingOrder` solved that problem). The default-generated SpriteKit project includes the line of code that explicitly sets this parameter to `YES`.